# Filter out diagrams from document generation based on some kind of status

Tags: templates, enterprise-architect, documentation-generation

Problem: Document options let you use filter elements etc., but no diagrams.
I've tried this using name prefixes and filter them, without success.

I would be thankful for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to filter diagrams in templates is using the diagram type

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. Bellekens.
But filtering diagrams based on type is not what I want to archive.
I renamed specific diagrams with prefix “final_” and tried to use this SQL query as fragment in the Diagram Report: 

>SELECT t_diagram.Name as Name
>FROM t_diagram
>WHERE t_diagram.[Name] LIKE '*final*'
 

!(https://ibb.co/qMhF5jR)
But it is not working as expected.
Best,
Florian

Comment: No a fragment won't do you any good. The diagram type is the only thing you can use to filter diagrams in your template. Alternative is to nest the diagram under an element or package and filter out the elements/packages.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. At least I can stop try around with these fragments... Thanks!